# absolute positioned image in a floated div

Tags: css, image, html, absolute

I have a top bar and the links are set using float.In one of the links i have a floated div.In that div i want to show a absolute positioned image.I am using absolute because i do not want to show the full image only a part of it will be displayed.this is achieved by using top and left as

**CSS**

```
div.cont{
    max-width:50px;
    min-width:50px;
    height:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img{
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    top:-10px;
    left:-15px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <div class="cont">
        <img src="image url"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

But as image is absolute positioned it is shown outside that div.

How can overcome this and show the image in div?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide us a fiddle so that it will be easy to answer!

Comment: Why don't you use the image as a background for that div?

Comment: add `position:relative` to div.cont.  also why do you have a max and min width of the same value? why not just use `width` as you have set your overflow to hidden

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the position on the parent div:

```
div.cont{
      max-width:50px;
      min-width:50px;
      height:50px;
      overflow:hidden;
      position:relative;
}
```

When you position something absolutely, it's positioned relative to the next positioned ancestor. If you don't specify the positioning then the ancestor will be the body.

Answer (score 4):

By default, absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to the viewport. Add `position: relative` to your floated div. This will position the image inside relative to its parent, rather than relative to the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-top` and `margin-left` instead of `left:` and top:` on the img.